# Error with Entity matching package deepmatcher

Tags: python, entity, matching

Getting below Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-2d323ffe212f> in <module>()
----> 1 train, validation, test = dm.data.process(path='/content/', train='train.csv', validation='validation.csv', test='test.csv')

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/deepmatcher/data/process.py in _check_header(header, id_attr, left_prefix, right_prefix, label_attr, ignore_columns)
     32         if attr not in (id_attr, label_attr) and attr not in ignore_columns:
     33             if not attr.startswith(left_prefix) and not attr.startswith(right_prefix):
---> 34                 raise ValueError('Attribute ' + attr + ' is not a left or a right table '
     35                                  'column, not a label or id and is not ignored. Not sure '
     36                                  'what it is...')

ValueError: Attribute ltable_id is not a left or a right table column, not a label or id and is not ignored. Not sure what it is...
```

I am using the

[http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~anhai/data1/deepmatcher_data/Textual/Company/company_exp_data.zip](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eanhai/data1/deepmatcher_data/Textual/Company/company_exp_data.zip)

dataset for this learning, because previous test with my own dataset gave the same error.

Code:

import deepmatcher as dm
train, validation, test = dm.data.process(path='/content/', train='train.csv', validation='validation.csv', test='test.csv')

That's it. I am following below repo github.com/anhaidgroup/deepmatcher

Looking for better understanding and possible solve. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could show minimal working code - so we could see what you do, what modules you import - and we could test this code on our comptuers.

Comment: import deepmatcher as dm                                                                                                     train, validation, test = dm.data.process(path='/content/', train='train.csv', validation='validation.csv', test='test.csv')          That's it.  I am following below repo------  https://github.com/anhaidgroup/deepmatcher

Comment: put it in question. It will be more readable and more people will see it so more peole may help you.

Comment: I don't know this module but based on error message all problem can be data in csv. It may need some preprocessing before it can be used in deepmatcher. It seems it has column `ltable_id` but it may need column with name `id` or it has to be first or last (label) column. Or maybe it need only two columns - left and right.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it but error message may suggest that it needs special columns to work.

And first look at page with repo [DeepMatch](https://github.com/anhaidgroup/deepmatcher) can confirm it.

There is example table which has columns with name `Left ...` and `Right ...`.

There was also link to [Get Started](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/anhaidgroup/deepmatcher/blob/master/examples/getting_started.ipynb) in which you can see

```
Step 1. Process labeled data¶

Left" attributes (required): ... 
   These column names are expected to be prefixed with "left_" by default.

"Right" attributes (required): "... 
   These column names are expected to be prefixed with "right_" by default.
```

Which shows that columns need prefix `left_`, `right_` but your data has columns `ltable_id`, `rtable_id`. So you have to change column names after you load it and before you use it with `DeepMatch`

---

**EDIT:**

In repo is also link [Data Processing](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/anhaidgroup/deepmatcher/blob/master/examples/data_processing.ipynb)

And there you can see

```
"Left" attributes (required):  ...
  This can be customized by setting the left_prefix parameter (e.g., use "ltable_" as the prefix).
"Right" attributes (required): ...
  This can be customized by setting the right_prefix parameter (e.g., use "rtable_" as the prefix).
```

and it shows example code

```
dm.data.process(... left_prefix='left_', right_prefix='right_', ...)
```

which can means you can do

```
dm.data.process(... left_prefix='ltable_', right_prefix='rtable_', ...)
```

---

**EDIT:**

I tested it and it resolves this problem with `company_exp_data.zip`.

```
import deepmatcher as dm 

train, validation, test = dm.data.process(
    path='/content/',
    #path='exp_data', 
    train='train.csv', 
    validation='valid.csv', 
    test='test.csv',
    
    left_prefix='ltable_',
    right_prefix='rtable_',
)
```

But next it gives other problem.

```
RuntimeError: Google drive link https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1Vih8gAmgBnuYDxfblbT94P6WjB7s1ZSh is currently unavailable, because the quota was exceeded.
```

It tries to read some data from `Google Drive` but `the quota was exceeded.`

Maybe it will need to download it manually and change source code to load it from local computer. But it is problem for new question. Or this problem should be send to author of this module. And he should put data on other server and change source code.

---

**Summarizing:** all your problem is you didn't read documentation.

Comment: yeah I see it now, I didn't read the documentation completely. I got stuck on the getting started section. I had tried with left_ and right_ in my dataset, when it didn't work I was very lost but your explanation makes sense. Thank you. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Extra information(might or might not be helpful.. still): As I mentioned, I started out with my dataset and that was when I first saw the error and I finally solved the issue. I was splitting my data into train and test, and then creating csv files and while creating the files I didn't set the index to false and that was creating a blank header, which in turn created error in process.py. Now, that's solved and I was still using the left_ right_ there. But all cool. Thanks again!